# Fix item in a scrollview

Tags: android, uiscrollview

I want to have a static imageView inside a ScrollView. I need this image to stay in the same screen position even if the user scrolls. The problem is that the ScrollView accepts only one child element.

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/finishedGameListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/yourTurnListView"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theirTurnTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/yourTurnListView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/their_turn"/>

    <ImageView  <!-- I want this to be fixed -->
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/theirTurnListView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/yourTurnListView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/yourTurnListView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- `ScrollView` can not be used in conjuction with `ListView`, `ListView` will not work properly.
- If you really want to do this, try this code:

  ```
  <FrameLayout>
      <ScrollView/>
      <ImageView/>
  </FrameLayout>
  ```